# CSS automatically linked to HTML with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a style.css file in app/assets/stylesheets for my Ruby on Rails project. I added some styling and started up the server. I didn't put any `<link href...>` or `stylesheet_link_tag` anywhere in any html.erb file but every page had the css changes I wrote in style.css

Additionally, I now have to restart the server every time I make a change to the CSS in order to see those changes in the browser. Has anyone ran into this before? By the way, I am using action cable. I also don't have a public/assets folder.

application.js

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("jquery")
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    alert("Hello!");
})
```

application.css

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

style.css

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#left, #right {float:left}
#left {width: 30%;}
#right {width: 70%;}
```

Comment: Rails version and setup?

Comment: Rails 6.0.3 and what do you mean by setup?

Comment: Are you using webpacker? I believe that's the default in Rails 6.

Comment: Also please add your `application.css` and `application.js` files to the question.

Comment: I'll admit that I am still baffled by Webpack. Its "simplicity" seems to be accompanied with a lot of assumption that people will just be able to adjust to it without documentation. It's for JS but can also be used for CSS.